# How do I disassociate an instance of AVAudioPlayer from a View in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, avaudioplayer

(Preface with I am very new to programming and Swift)

I am making an alarm app and so I have an AudioPlayer class based mostly on the one outlined in this instructional but with some modifications for looping that I needed:

https://blckbirds.com/post/voice-recorder-app-in-swiftui-1/

I have a timer and an .onRecieve associated with a view that creates my onscreen clock.  Timer goes off, sound plays through an @ObservedObject created from my class, tap a button and it triggers the .stop() function.  That all works for the most part as long as I stay on the main view.

The issue I am running into is that under certain circumstances it appears that view changes crash the app. Specifically:

"Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"

On the line in my class related to .stop().  I interpret this to be that there is no audioplayer  found to stop and my guess is that it's because it was created in a different view that is no longer present?

A typical situation is I have a landscape view that is a large version of just the clock whereas the portrait view has controls.  If in landscape when the alarm goes off and the sound triggers, switching to portrait either crashes right away or when I tap the button to stop.

My thinking was to move the audio instance outside of the views or into a background process of some sort that is independent of the view status, but I can't figure out how to do that or even if my analysis of the issue is correct.

Another approach I attempted to take was to force the screen back to the original portrait view before triggering the audio so that I was only dealing with the audio in the one view (a user interface behavior that wasn't ideal but acceptable to me).  This appears to now not play the sound at all, and then still crash when stop is tapped.

Could anyone help me understand what is going on with my audioplayer object and how I might approach this problem?  Thanks,

Dan

Comment: Would you show your code?

Comment: Yes. It would be helpful to post your code. We're not going to be able to tell you much without actually seeing what you're doing and what line specifically is getting the error. That being said, a possible solution you can try is to create your audio player as a property of SceneDelegate, then attach it to the contentView as an environmental object. That will make sure it persists across all views.

Comment: I realized as I asked that I should include code but it was very scattered and mixed with unrelated code. That said I think I figured out a solution by moving the creation of the audio instance and trigger out to part of my Content View which I believe is "top level"?  Not quite what Mightknow suggested but related I think. I am going to test this for now and if I run into issues I will try the suggestion or return to post code.  I will post code on future questions. Thank you both for attempting to respond to me.